# Typescript - create an object selecting the class dynamically via its name

Tags: typescript

I have a Typescrip application where I need to implement different classes representing different control logic (e.g. `ControlLogicA`, `ControlLogicB`, `ControlLogicC`). All these classes are extensions of the same abstract superclass (`ControlLogicAbstract`).

Which control logic to apply is determined at configuration time and therefore, at runtime, the only thing I know is the name of the class which I need to use in the form of a string (e.g. `controlLogicClassName`).

Now the question(s):

1) Is it possible in Typescript to create an instance of a class starting only from the name of the class (e.g. knowing only `controlLogicClassName`)?

2) Is it possible to do this both in a browser environement and in a Node environment?

3) If this can be done in a browser environment, is it something that is supported also by old versions of browsers (let's say IE9 and above)?

Additional question: is it possible to query (at runtime) an abstract Typescript class (e.g. `ControlLogicAbstract`) to get the list of all its available subclasses (in my example ControlLogicA, ControlLogicB and ControlLogicC)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have something like:

```
interface ControlLogicConstrctor {
    new (): ControlLogicAbstract;
}

abstract class ControlLogicAbstract {}

class ControlLogic1 extends ControlLogicAbstract {}

class ControlLogic2 extends ControlLogicAbstract {}

var ctors: { [name: string]: ControlLogicConstrctor } = {
    "control1": ControlLogic1,
    "control2": ControlLogic2,
    // ...
    "controlN": ControlLogicN
}

function factory(name: string): ControlLogicAbstract {
    let ctor = ctors[name];

    if (!ctor) {
        return null;
    }

    return new ctor();
}
```

This should work fine in browsers and node.
Basically in javascript these classes are just functions, as this for example:

```
class MyClass {
    private x: number;

    constructor() {
        this.x = 4;
    }
}
```

Compiles into:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        this.x = 4;
    }
    return MyClass;
}());
```

So you end up with `MyClass` being just a function.

No, you do not have a way to get all of the extending classes.
This is not supported in ts/js, you'll need to somehow handle that yourself (like having a data structure with the classes/ctors in it, kinda like my `ctors` object).